# How to change depending on the resource name

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have list names.
Resource.denis - Image. 
each name is the name of the resource

```
foreach(var name in Names)
    m_path.Add(new DataPath(Resources.denis, name));
```

without the loop so it would look like

```
names.Add("denis");
names.Add("dima");

m_path.Add(new DataPath(Resources.denis, name[0]))
m_path.Add(new DataPath(Resources.dima, name[1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have a look at the code generated for you when you add images to your resources, in ***Resources.Designer.cs***. Behind the scenes, it does exactly what you are trying to achieve. It probably looks like this:

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap denis {
    get {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("denis", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

And this is how you access your resources with a string.

Comment: Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject

Comment: Yes, it's just not there because the code i posted is directly from inside the resources class.